# Counting permutations : too many separate possibities

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, expected-value

5 students and their parents( 10 people ) want to stand in a line. For every formation of these 15 people in the line there is an "adj". adj indicates the number of positions in which a student is standing next to one of the parents.(not necessarily of their own ) for example in this formation
PPPSSPPSPSPPSPP
adj = 8
The question is to find the average value of adj in all possible permutations. Considering all parents are the same (P) and all students too(S)
I have tried calculating the value of each possible adj. (0<adj<12) but each one seems to have too many separate possible formations.
Like for adj = 3
We can use either this formation
PSSPSSSPP... where the number of parents in between students and at each end of the line can vary from 1 to 13 and then there is this other possible formation
SSPSSSPP... which has it's own separate permutations.

Comment: Sounds like a job for linearity of expectation.

Comment: @saulspatz Could you please explain more? I'm not familiar with that concept.

Comment: E(aX+bY)=aE(X)+bE(Y), where $a, b$ are constants, and $X,Y$ are random variables.  Note that this is true even if X and Y are dependent.

Comment: Thanks to @saulspatz for saving me from several hours of work in trying to
construe this as a "stars and bars problem on steroids", using 
https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/ as a starting point.
**Instead**, I read 
https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/.  By this, you
have to compute the expected number of parent-neighbors that one student will
have, and then simply multiply that by 5.  You have to consider that the 
student may be at one of the endpoints (chance = 2/15).  You also have to consider
that among the other 14 people are 10 adults.

Comment: No - quasi's answer nails it.  Picking out specific cases: **if** student on endpt, chance of 1 parent-neighbor is (10/14).  **If** student not on endpt, chance of (for example) 1 parent-neighbor is $2 \times $ chance of student on left $\times$ **resultant chance** of parent on right.  Does this help?

Comment: It does. I was a little bit confused but i think i get it now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a given student, let $p_k$ be the probability that the student is adjacent to $k$ parents, where $0\le k\le 2$.

Then we get
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
p_0&=
\left(\frac{2}{15}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{4}{14}\right)
+
\left(\frac{13}{15}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{4}{14}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{3}{13}\right)
=
\frac{2}{21}
\\[6pt]
p_1&=
\left(\frac{2}{15}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{10}{14}\right)
+
\left(\frac{13}{15}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{4}{14}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{10}{13}{\,\cdot\,}2\right)
=
\frac{10}{21}
\\[6pt]
p_2&=
\frac{13}{15}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{10}{14}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{9}{13}
=
\frac{3}{7}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
The contribution of each student to the expected number of student-parent adjacencies is equal to
$$
0{\,\cdot\,}p_0\;+\;1{\,\cdot\,}p_1\;+\;2{\,\cdot\,}p_2
=
0{\,\cdot\,}\frac{2}{21}\;+\;1{\,\cdot\,}\frac{10}{21}\;+\;2{\,\cdot\,}\frac{3}{7}
=
\frac{4}{3}
$$
hence since there are $5$ students, the expected number of  student-parent adjacencies is equal to
$$
5{\,\cdot\,}\frac{4}{3}
=
\frac{20}{3}
\approx
6.67
$$

Comment: Thank you very much that helped alot